# Does CosmosDB Graph Api support hasNot?

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb

I'm testing out CosmosDB's Gremlin support and was looking at using hasNot in a query step. According the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support) I can find I see

> has - Used to filter properties, vertices, and edges. Supports hasLabel, hasId, hasNot, and has variants.

Working against the default Azure example graph from the Gremlin console I can run

```
gremlin> :> g.V().has('firstName')
```

and get reasonable results I would expect yet,

```
gremlin> :> g.V().hasNot('firstName')
```

results in the very confidence inspiring stack trace response from Azure (with ids removed just in case).

```
Gremlin Query Compilation Error: Traversal Script: Failed to compile query:
(1,74): error CS1061: Type `Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.GraphTraversal' does not contain a definition for `hasNot' and no extension method `hasNot' of type `Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.GraphTraversal' could be fou$
d. Are you missing an assembly reference?
D:\local\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\<removed>\<removed>\assembly\dl3\<removed>\<removed>\Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
                ExceptionType : GraphCompileException
                Source : Microsoft.Azure.Graphs
                Context : <removed>
                RequestId : <removed>
                Scope : graphcmd-emitcode
                Status : ScriptEvaluationError
                HResult : 0x80131500
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Common.MonoTraversalScript.HandleCompileError(Tuple`2& evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.Common.MonoTraversalScript.Compile()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.GraphCommand.<ExecuteTraversalAsync>b__38_0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.GraphCommand.<ExecuteTraversalAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.GremlinServer.DefaultGraphRequestProcessor.<CreateGremlinResponseInternalAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
```

The key part is of course that portion of the first line that appears to say that hasNot is not appropriately defined in Azure's .NET dll that's being used to compile the query on the server.

A similar result comes from the query explorer in the dashboard.

This can be worked around (to some extent at least) with

```
gremlin> :> g.V().not(has('firstName'))
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a workaround other than what you've provided, but just FYI there is no query compilation happening server side. The gremlin is parsed and translated into Document queries on the client side. You can examine the outbound network calls with Fiddler or another proxy to see exactly what queries are being issued.

Comment: I'll look into verifying that, but doing it client side seems rather unlikely since I'm running in the JRE on TinkerPop code rather than using a C# dll. Of course debugging by using Fiddler from the .NET interface to look at the raw calls may end up being a useful debugging technique to see when errors are almost certainly on Azure's side rather than the Gremlin query side.

Comment: This is now supported, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `hasNot()` step is currently not exposed on CosmosDB Graph, which looks to be an oversight on our part.

I've added this issue to our backlog, and since it appears to be partially implemented already, it's likely to be available for the next service release (~ 2 weeks).